# Center website issue

Tags: css, web, center

im looking for center my website in the middle of the browser. This is my website:

http://marcosballester1.hol.es/test/test2.html

Left side is correctly centered, but right side no. Actual Code:

```
<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `word-wrap: break-word` to `.wrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have content without spaces:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word; // this rule will resolve your problem
}
```

Comment: now i have another problem , i cant add height, how can i? the wrapper has a yellow background, how i can add height to it? [ALREADY SOLVED SORY]

Answer (score 0):

Since your text is in *unbreakable*, you need to use **[word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)** property with `break-word` value:

> Indicates that normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary
>   points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

```
#wrapper { 
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```